# Regex to separate and phone numbers of same network from a list of phone numbers

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have been had a tough time trying to figure this out.

Let me explain my needs this way:

1. I am making a php sms sender script.
2. The recipients phone numbers will be typed inside a textarea, separated with commas
   eg : `2348064356853,2347065478934,2348167456845,2347123454680`.
3. These numbers would be a mixture of phone numbers from different mobile networks
4. Different APIs will handle the sms delivery to different phone groups (mobile networks) (eg. API1, handles Phones from NetworkA and NetworkB, while API2 will handle NetworkC, etc
5. I already know the formats of the numbers assigned to the various Phone Networks.

Here is the formats for all the available networks:

- All the phone numbers, are 13 digits in length, starting with 234,
- The first 6 digits in each phone number identifies a network
- All the networks have more than 1 unique identification numbers

below is the numbers assigned to the different networks:

- Network A - `234706, 234803, 234806, 234810, 234813, 234816 4235940,`
- Network B - `234705, 234805, 234807, 234815,`
- Network C - `234809, 234817, 234818, 234708`
- Network D - `234802, 234808, 234812`
- Network E - `234702, 234819, 234709, 234704, 234707

My Challenge is how to separate the phone numbers from these different networks and group them into separate variables.

Please, I need someone to help me with this.

Comment: In what implementation? PHP? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network A

```
/234(?:706|803|806|810|813|816)\d{7}/
```

Network B

```
/234(?:705|805|807|815)\d{7}/
```

Network C

```
/234(?:708|809|817|818)\d{7}/
```

Network D

```
/234(?:802|808|812)\d{7}/
```

Network E

```
/234(?:702|704|707|709|819)\d{7}/
```

You can use a `preg_match_all` per expression above, with the `PREG_SET_ORDER` option so that all your numbers are neatly in an array, `$matches[0]`.

The expressions could be anchored (`^` or `$`) or boundaries or lookaround assertions could have been used, but I wasn't sure exactly what your inputs were.

Comment: I can't beleive that my problem has been solved in seconds after posting. Thanks a million @acheong87. you are the man.

Answer (score 0):

1- Separate Network prefixes, something like:

```
networks={
    "505 404 506 606",
    "236 848 488 993"
    etc
};
```

2- Get if a number is valid, and separate it:
`/234(\d{3})(\d{7})/gm` this will make 2 groups, one with the prefix and other with the number so you just must find the prefix and send the number over the index of the networks array where you have found your prefix.

Edit: [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hP8oW6)

Answer (score 0):

Here's your regex `(?P<NETA>234(?:706|803|806|810|813|816)\d{7})|(?P<NETB>234(?:705|805|807|815)\d{7})|(?P<NETC>234(?:809|817|818|708)\d{7})|(?P<NETD>234(?:802|808|812)\d{7})|(?P<NETE>234(?:702|819|709|704|707)\d{7})`

and here's some helpful code to create your own next time

```
<?php

    $networx = array(
        'A'     => array( 706, 803, 806, 810, 813, 816 ),
        'B'     => array( 705, 805, 807, 815 ),
        'C'     => array( 809, 817, 818, 708 ),
        'D'     => array( 802, 808, 812 ),
        'E'     => array( 702, 819, 709, 704, 707 )
    );


    $regex = '';

    foreach ( $networx as $k => $nums ) {
        $nums = implode( '|', $nums );
        $regex .= ( $regex ? '|' : '' ) . "(?P<NET{$k}>234(?:{$nums})\d{7})";
    }


    $text = "Network A - 2347061234567, 234803, 234806, 234810, 234813, 23481 6 4235940,

    Network B - 234705, 2348051234567, 234807, 2348151234567,

    Network C - 234809, 234817, 2348181234567, 234708

    Network D- 234802, 2348081234567, 234812

    Network E - 234702, 234819, 234709, 234704, 234707";

    preg_match_all( "/{$regex}/", $text, $matches );

?>
```

The final var `$matches` will contain keys like `NETA`, `NETB`, ... `NETE` containing arrays with the corresponding numbers.

```
[NETB] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 2348051234567
        [2] => 2348151234567
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
    )
```